# Is a cached redirect loop possible?

Tags: http, browser-cache, http-redirect

**tldr:** 308 (permanent) redirects may be cached.  What happens when a redirect loop includes one or more (or all) cached responses?

**My situation:** Say I serve a page `/version-1` for a bit.  After a while I set up `/version-2` and start redirecting (code 308) all requests for `/version-1` to `/version-2`.  A while later I decide I actually preferred the first version and resume serving `/version-1` while redirecting (308 again) `/version-2` back to `/version-1`.

What is the expected behavior in this instance?  Will a browser reuse the cached redirect(s) (causing an redirect loop), or is there a defined way it should break out of the loop?

(Please note that I am not asking how to improve this site design.  It is an example to demonstrate my question.  I am asking what the RFCs/actual browsers have to say about the situation.)

The closest I've been able to find myself is [RFC 9110 Section 15.4](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#rfc.section.15.4) which states:

> A client SHOULD detect and intervene in cyclical redirections (i.e., "infinite" redirection loops).

But afaict says nothing about eg. not reusing cached responses when attempting to resolve a redirect loop.  What else is there?